# Javascript previous is same as global window object?

Tags: javascript, forms, window

The functionality is - 
When I click a link, a window opens which has some items that can be checked/unchecked. After i close the window and reopen it, I should be able to see my previous check/uncheck.

While debugging, I came across "previous" object. When I see in console, it is same as "window" object. I don't see a "previous" object defined anywhere. Is this any global object, which i suspect is used in this code to get the previous form data like the check/uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass information between windows you'll have to do it as session data. [HTML5's Web Storage specification](https://w3c.github.io/webstorage/) can be used for this:

> This specification defines an API for persistent data storage of key-value pair data in Web clients.

You can add an event listener for checkbox click using [vanilla JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

Since you didn't include any code in the question I haven't included any in the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! my q is still not answered sir. Is there a previous object by default?

Comment: I'm not aware of any `previous` object.